# Для чего нужны данные типы?

Tags: c++

int8_t
uint8_t
int16_t
uint16_t
int32_t
uint32_t
int64_t
uint64_t

Я понимаю что они определяют статический размер переменных на всех устройствах но для чего это нужно. + почему нет аналогий для других типов?

Comment: Для каких "других типов"?

Answer (score 6):

> но для чего это нужно

Эти типы нужны тогда, когда переменная должна иметь точный размер при портировании программы на другую систему или компилятор. Например, если нам нужно работать с большим файлом, его размер можно представить как `size_t`. Но при компиляции под 32 бита такая переменная имеет размер 32 бита и программа будет работать неправильно с большими файлами. `uint64_t` гарантирует правильную работу в любой системе.

Другой пример: поле в двоичном файле занимает 4 байта и нам нужно его считать в переменную. Тип `int` может быть 2-х, 4-х, и 8-и байтовым, поэтому при чтении в переменную `int` в первом случае испортится память, а в последнем - старшие 4 байта переменной будут содержать мусор. Решение - использовать `int32_t`.

> почему нет аналогий для других типов?

Есть. Для символов есть `char8_t`, `char16_t`, и `char32_t`. Для вещественных - `float` и `double`. Остается только `bool`, но для него особой проблемы нет.

Comment: "uint64_t гарантирует правильную работу в любой системе" и в 32 bit?

Comment: @Mike Waters, гарантирует правильную работу описанного примера. Да, в любой системе, потому что в любой системе это будет 64-битовое значение.

Comment: "`uint64_t` гарантирует правильную работу в любой системе." Это неправда. Все типы с точными размерами являются *опциональными*, т.е. их наличие в конкретной реализации *не гарантируется*. По этой причине формально использовать их для портирования можно лишь с такой оговоркой. Типа `uint64_t` в конкретной реализации может просто отсутствовать.

Comment: @Mike Waters: А в чем проблема?

Comment: @AnT, даже если в какой-то системе они не определены, определить их самому через `typedef` дело пары минут. Так что их надо использовать в любом случае.

Comment: @freim: Нет. Причина, по которой они могут отсутствовать, - это не лень разработчиков, а то, что их там просто *невозможно* определить в силу аппаратных особенностей платформы. Как вы предлагаете определить `uint16_t` в системе, где `char` имеет размер 32 бита?

Comment: @AnT, определю через `short`. Нет, ну в самом деле - вы что, хотите сказать, что есть реальная система с неполной системой типов, где 16-битовое целое отсутствует в любой форме?

Comment: @freim, short в такой системе тоже будет 32-битным -) Насчет наличия системы -- посмотрите на TMS-ы

Comment: @avp, если вы знаете лучший вариант, чем использовать типы фиксированного размера, хотелось бы его услышать.

Comment: @freim В такой системе `short` будет тоже иметь 32 бита. Реальные системы, разумеется, есть! В области embedded платформ их навалом, с байтом в 16 или 32 бита. И да, никакого 16-битного целого на платформе с 32-битным байтом нет. Именно поэтому точные типы являются опциональными.

Comment: @AnT, согласен, со встроенными системами есть такой момент. Тем не менее, это никак не отменяет ценности типов фиксированного размера и необходимости их использовать для переносимости. К тому же основные проблемы происходят от укорачивания типов. С типами большего размера проблем на порядок меньше.

Comment: @freim Совершенно верно. Именно поэтому действительно портабельный код должен писаться не в терминах типов *точной* ширины, а терминах типов *достаточной* ширины. Именно поэтому существуют *обязательные* типы вроде `uint_least16_t`.

Comment: @freim, а я ведь не говорил, что типы фиксированного размера не надо использовать. Я сказал, что не всегда этого можно добиться "пионерскими наскоками". Не знаю точно, но могу предположить, что в системах подобных тем же TMS такие типы могут быть встроены в компилятор (ага, работа с ними может оказаться менее эффективной, чем с natural)/ И да, программа с такими типами может оказаться не переносимой (впрочем, вообще переносимость не стоит делать основной целью, но это отдельная (м.б. философская -)) тема)

Comment: @avp, честно говоря, с трудом представляю себе программу, которую необходимо перенести с десктопа в умную кофеварку. Встроенные системы это все-таки свой мир, и программы обычно сразу пишут именно под них, с учетом их всевозможных вывихов. В обычной жизни, когда мы говорим о переносимости, это редко выходит за пределы стандартной тройки Windows-Linux-Mac.

Comment: @AnT почему 64 bit программы не работают на 32 bit системах? как я понимаю uint64_t занимает 64 bit т.е. он не поместиться в 32 bit

Comment: @Mike Waters: 64-битные программы не работают на 32-битных системах потому, что используют 64-битные процессорные инструкции, которые 32-битный процессор не понимает в упор.